# Sum the values of a WPF datagrid column without additional query?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I'm populating the following WPF datagrid:

[image]

Using the following method:

```
private void ButtonFilterWorkflowWhenClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var db = new DatabaseHandle();



    dataGridWorkflow.ItemsSource = db.DisplayHealthIndicator(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now);


    labelWorkflowLastLoaded.Content = "Last Loaded at " + DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " with " +
                              dataGridWorkflow.Items.Count.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " total events.";


}
```

Which references the following class object:

```
public DataView DisplayHealthIndicator(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    string queryString = "[marlin].[support_retrieve_workflow_history]";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date_from", startDate.Date);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date_to", endDate.Date);

            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);

            connection.Close();
            return dt.DefaultView;

        }
    }

}
```

I'm trying to find a way that I can find the sum of the total column so I can add it to my label but having no success. I can do this with a second query but I'd like to avoid that wherever possible. How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to enumerate the rows in your `DataView`, something like:

```
dataGridWorkflow.ItemsSource = db.DisplayHealthIndicator(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now);
DataView dv = (DataView)dataGridWorkflow.ItemsSource;
DataRowCollection drc = dv.Table.Rows;
IEnumerator rowEnum = drc.GetEnumerator();
int sum = 0;
while (rowEnum.MoveNext())
{
    sum += (int)((DataRow)rowEnum.Current)[3];//assuming the 'Total' column has index 3.
}
labelWorkflowLastLoaded.Content = "Last Loaded at " + DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " with " + sum.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " total events.";
```

**Edit**: I changed it so that you should be able to just copy and paste into your code.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm a fledgling Junior and although I understand the concept when I tried to put this in place I failed - miserably. Could you elaborate a bit more?